# Is "round" a verb in this phrase?

Tags: phrases

> These days, advertisers not only offer free samples, but free cars, free houses, and free **trips round the world** as well.

Is *round* a verb in the phrase *trips round the world*?

Comment: http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/round_3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, "round" in that line is short for "around", a preposition.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.Please see my update. I think "round the world"  just works like an adj . I don't familiar with this phrase structure.  Can you give me more examples like that.

Comment: I can see clearly see where you are getting that, it does look like that if you look at the line in a certain way. However, even within that context, the word "round" is still a preposition. I'm here with nothing better to do. If you would like to discuss it further in chat, it would be my pleasure. It looks like I have forgotten to upvote your question. I'll do that now. I think that will give you the points necessary to enter chat. Just say @Jolenealaska and I'll hear your "ping".

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with this website either :p. I updated my question just because I want you to see  the original sentence ,then I can be sure that your answer is right. I should put it there at the very beginning.    I'm learning English these days . Thank you for helping me with this question. :)

Comment: You, and learners like you are the reason this site exists. I hope I helped, and I hope to continue to help. If you click on "StackExchange" on the top bar of this page, you should see the word "chat". Clicking on that will bring you to yet another menu, the first option will be the main room chat room for this site. We're talking about lyrical language right now, you might like it.

Answer (score 2):

"round" here is the same as *around*, which is a preposition.

Comment: There is a link now on a comment attached to the OP. That link is directly on-point.